# How can i download .cs files from the site?

Tags: c#

I have this two functions. Now they will download and save specific images from the website in the url variable.

But now i want to change the GetAllImages() function content and to use the csFiles string website to get from the site all the .cs files and save them to the hard disk.
So i need to change the GetAllImages function and also to modify the DownloadImage function to download *.cs files and not images.

How can i do it ?

```
public void GetAllImages()
        {

            // Bing Image Result for Cat, First Page
            string url = "http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat&go=&form=QB&qs=n";
            string csFiles = "http://open-hardware-monitor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Hardware/";

            // For speed of dev, I use a WebClient
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string html = client.DownloadString(url);

            // Load the Html into the agility pack
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            // Now, using LINQ to get all Images
            /*List<HtmlNode> imageNodes = null;
            imageNodes = (from HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")
                          where node.Name == "img"
                          && node.Attributes["class"] != null
                          && node.Attributes["class"].Value.StartsWith("sg_t")
                          select node).ToList();*/

           var imageLinks = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
    .Where(n => n.Attributes["class"].Value == "sg_t")
    .Select(n => HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(n.Attributes["src"].Value)["amp;url"]).ToList();


            foreach (string node in imageLinks)
            {
                y++;
                //Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["src"].Value);
                richTextBox1.Text += node + Environment.NewLine;
                Image t = DownloadImage(node);
                t.Save(@"d:\test\" + y.ToString("D6" + ".jpg"));

            }


        }


        public Image DownloadImage(string _URL)
        {
            Image _tmpImage = null;

            try
            {
                // Open a connection
                System.Net.HttpWebRequest _HttpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(_URL);

                _HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

                // You can also specify additional header values like the user agent or the referer: (Optional)
                //_HttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
                //_HttpWebRequest.Referer = "http://www.google.com/";

                // set timeout for 20 seconds (Optional)
                _HttpWebRequest.Timeout = 60000;

                // Request response:
                System.Net.WebResponse _WebResponse = _HttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                // Open data stream:
                System.IO.Stream _WebStream = _WebResponse.GetResponseStream();

                // convert webstream to image
                _tmpImage = Image.FromStream(_WebStream);

                // Cleanup
                _WebResponse.Close();
                _WebResponse.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception _Exception)
            {
                // Error
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString());
                return null;
            }

            return _tmpImage;
        }
```

Comment: You will have to download the directory listing and parse it to get URLs of the files. For the parsing, you could try using a HTML parser, but using something simple like regexes might work here too.

Answer (score 5):

You are taking a surprisingly silly approach to downloading this project from its Subversion repository. Instructions on how to do it correctly are available on the project page:

https://code.google.com/p/open-hardware-monitor/source/checkout

Alternatively, you may want to just get one of their packaged downloads:

https://code.google.com/p/open-hardware-monitor/downloads/list